# Detect Cycles in a DSE graph

Tags: tinkerpop3, datastax-enterprise-graph

Using TinkerPop3 as the interface to a DSE graph. Is there any easy way to detect cycles in a graph or rather not visit an already visited vertex.

Specifically in my case, There is a "GROUP" vertex and there can be a group of groups. I will like to list all "USERS" in a group of groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you worked with the Gremlin steps SimplePath or ClyclicPath ?  http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/reference/#cyclicpath-step

SimplePath sounds like it will do what you are interested in doing.